# Application.Match not exact value

Tags: vba, excel

Have a piece of code that looks for matches between 2 sheets (sheet1 is customer list and `rData` is copied pdf with invoices). It usually is exact match but in some cases I'm looking for 6 first characters that matches `rData`

```
Dim rData   As Variant
Dim r       As Variant
Dim r20  As Variant
Dim result  As Variant
Dim i       As Long

rData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:A60000") 

r20 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C33")

For Each r In r20
  result = Application.Match(r, rData, 0)
  If Not IsError(result) Then
    For i = 1 To 5
      If (result - i) > 0 Then
        If (Left(Trim(rData(result - i, 1)), 3) = "418") Then
          MsgBox "customer: " & r & ". invoice: " & rData(result - i, 1)
        End If
      End If
    Next
    For i = 1 To 15
      If (result + i) > 0 Then
        If (Left(Trim(rData(result + i, 1)), 3) = "418") Then
          MsgBox "customer: " & r & ". invoice: " & rData(result + i, 1)
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Only part of this that is giving me a headache is this part `result = Application.Match(r, rData, 0)`. How do it get match for not exact match?

Sample of Sheet1[image]

This is what more or less looks like. Matching after CustomerNumber# is easy because they are the same every invoice. BUT sometimes invoice does not have it so I'm searching after CustomerName and sometimes they have uppercase letters, sometimes there is extra stuff behind it and therefore it cannot find exact match. 
Hope it makes sense.

Comment: By definition (`For Each r in r20`),  `r` will be in `r20` and will match exactly... why do you want non-exact matches? What kind of data do you have in r20? Please give some sample data

Comment: @CallumDA Sample added.

Comment: Consider changing all your test strings to upper case if you want to test mixed case text; also you can use REGEX or InStr functions instead of Match. google 'Excel VBA string functions' for a good range of potential solutions

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak If you've already looked at my answer, it had some bugs in it. I fixed them now, and added extra code and notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the customer name from your customer list to the customer name in the invoice even if it has extra characters appended, you can use the wildcard `*` in `Match()`.

You also have a typo in the `Match()` function. `r20` should be `rData`.

This is your code with the fixes applied:

```
Sub Test()
  'v4
  Dim rData   As Variant
  Dim r       As Variant
  Dim r20  As Variant
  Dim result  As Variant
  Dim i       As Long

  rData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:A60000")

  r20 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C33")

  For Each r In r20
    result = Application.Match(r & "*", rData, 0) ' <~ Fixed here
    If Not IsError(result) Then
      For i = 1 To 5
        If (result - i) > 0 Then
          If (Left(Trim(rData(result - i, 1)), 3) = "418") Then
            MsgBox "customer: " & r & ". invoice: " & rData(result - i, 1)
          End If
        End If
      Next
      For i = 1 To 15
        If (result + i) > 0 Then
          If (Left(Trim(rData(result + i, 1)), 3) = "418") Then
            MsgBox "customer: " & r & ". invoice: " & rData(result + i, 1)
          End If
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next r

End Sub
```

**Notes:**

- `Match()` is case insensitive, so it works with different capitalisations.
- The data in `Sheets(2)` must all be text for `Match()` to work correctly with wildcards.

---

**EDIT1:** <sub><sup>New better version</sup></sub>

**EDIT2:** <sub><sup>Refactored constants and made data ranges dynamic</sup></sub>

**EDIT3:** <sub><sup>Allows for *any* prefix to an invoice number of a fixed length</sup></sub>

The following is a better, rewritten version of your code:

```
Sub MuchBetter()
  'v3
  Const s_InvoiceDataWorksheet As String = "Sheet2"
  Const s_InvoiceDataColumn    As String = "A:A"
  Const s_CustomerWorksheet    As String = "Sheet1"
  Const s_CustomerStartCell    As String = "C2"
  Const s_InvoiceNumPrefix     As String = "418"
  Const n_InvoiceNumLength       As Long = 8
  Const n_InvScanStartOffset     As Long = -5
  Const n_InvScanEndOffset       As Long = 15

  Dim ƒ As Excel.WorksheetFunction: Set ƒ = Excel.WorksheetFunction ' Shortcut

  With Worksheets(s_InvoiceDataWorksheet).Range(s_InvoiceDataColumn)
    With .Parent.Range(.Cells(1), .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      Dim varInvoiceDataArray As Variant
      varInvoiceDataArray = ƒ.Transpose(.Cells.Value2)
    End With
  End With
  With Worksheets(s_CustomerWorksheet).Range(s_CustomerStartCell)
    With .Parent.Range(.Cells(1), .EntireColumn.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      Dim varCustomerArray  As Variant
      varCustomerArray = ƒ.Transpose(.Cells.Value2)
    End With
  End With

  Dim varCustomer As Variant
  For Each varCustomer In varCustomerArray
    Dim dblCustomerIndex As Double
    dblCustomerIndex = Application.Match(varCustomer & "*", varInvoiceDataArray, 0)
    If Not IsError(dblCustomerIndex) _
    And varCustomer <> vbNullString _
    Then
      Dim i As Long
      For i = ƒ.Max(dblCustomerIndex + n_InvScanStartOffset, 1) _
          To ƒ.Min(dblCustomerIndex + n_InvScanEndOffset, UBound(varInvoiceDataArray))
        Dim strInvoiceNum As String
        strInvoiceNum = Right$(Trim$(varInvoiceDataArray(i)), n_InvoiceNumLength)
        If (Left$(strInvoiceNum, Len(s_InvoiceNumPrefix)) = s_InvoiceNumPrefix) Then
          MsgBox "customer: " & varCustomer & ". invoice: " & strInvoiceNum
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next varCustomer

End Sub
```

**Notes:**

- It is a good idea to use constants so all literal values are typed once only and kept grouped together.
- Using the [RVBA](//www.xoc.net/standards/rvbanc.asp) naming convention greatly increases the readability of the code, and reduces the likelihood of bugs.
- Using long, appropriately named variables makes the code essentially self-documenting.
- Using `.Value2` whenever reading cell values is highly recommended (it avoids implicit casting, making it slightly faster as well as eliminating certain issues caused by the casting ).
- Surprisingly, in VBA there are good reasons to put a variable declaration as close as possible to the first use of the variable. Two such reasons are 1) it improves readability, and 2) it simplifies future refactoring. Just remember that the variable is not reinitialised every time the `Dim` is encountered. Initialisation only occurs the first time.
- The twin loops have been rolled into one according to the DRY principle.
- Whilst the check for an empty customer name/number is not strictly necessary if you can guarantee it will never be so, it is good defensive programming as an empty value will cause erroneous results.
- The negative index check inside the loop has been removed and replaced with the one-time use of the `Max()` worksheet function in the `For` statement.
- The `Min()` worksheet function is also used in the `For` statement to avoid trying to read past the end of the array.
- Always use worksheet functions on the `WorksheetFunction` object unless you are explicitly checking for errors, in which case use the `Application` object.

Comment: Works like charm but how do i add additional customers to array? There is over 50 of them. EDIT Additionally i had to change `Dim lngCustomerIndex As Long` to `Dim lngCustomerIndex As Variant` for it to work properly.

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak (－‸ლ) `Match()` actually returns a *Double*. I only tested on a short range :( Should have had `Dim dblCustomerIndex As Double`. Variant always works, of course ;-) I was half expecting you to ask about changing the number of customers. You could just change the `C2:C33` to the appropriate range. However, I'll upload a new version of the code that automatically adjusts for the number of customers as well as the length of the invoice data.

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak I've update the code and added more notes.

Comment: Is there a way to add something to `s_InvoiceNumPrefix`? I just notice that invoice numbers sometimes begin with `Invoice-Nr. 0418` instead of normal 418. `Const s_InvoiceNumPrefix     As String = "418" Or "Invoice-Nr. 0"` is not working.

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak Should be very easy. Are the invoice numbers composed of only digits? And are they 15 digits or less in length?

Comment: Sometimes they are composed of 8 digits starting with 418. But sometimes they are composed of this `Rechnungs-Nr. 0418*****`. Rechnung is german for invoice btw. ;)

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak OK. New version posted. It now takes the rightmost 8 characters and uses them as the invoice number. As for your attempt that didn't work, something similar to that could have been done. If there were more variations of the invoice numbers, I probably would have gone that way.

Comment: After some tests there is still an issue with it that ignores cells that contain `Rechnungs-Nr. 0418*****`. Is it possible maybe to search and delete phrase `Rechnungs-Nr. 0` so only invoice number that starts with `418` stays? I'm sorry to be bothering you all the time with it.

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak No problem. I've just retested the code and it works fine as long as there are **exactly** five **digits**, and no other non-space characters, after the `0418`. Deleting the `Rechnungs-Nr. 0` part beforehand *should* work, but it complicates the code, and shouldn't be necessary, as the current code should *also* work. In your comment, did you mean that all of the prefixed invoice numbers are being ignored, or only some of them? The only thing I can think of is that those invoice numbers are more than 5 cells before, or 15 cells after, the customer name. You can change…

Comment: …those values in the code. If that fails to work, would you upload a sample spreadsheet somewhere, containing at least one invoice number that is being ignored and the surrounding cells. Post the link to the spreadsheet in a comment.

Comment: As you suggested i tweaked `n_InvScanStartOffset` and `n_InvScanEndOffset` and that seemed to fix it.